# java with Oauth for Google and facebook authontication

Tags: java, openid

i wont to implement authentication using google and facebook in my application
any one share example that work for authentication in java webapp
without any java framework

i try with [socialaut](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/)
its using struts and spring framework but i not use that framework in my application so give any example that work in simple tomcat application without any framework

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i try with socialaut its using struts and spring framework but i not use that framework in my application so give any example that work in simple tomcat application without any framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code on login page request

```
 SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
  config.load(); // load your keys information 
  SocialAuthManager manager = new SocialAuthManager();
  manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);

  String successUrl = "http://localhost:8080/yourapp/status
  String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl("facebook", successUrl);
  session.setAttribute("authManager", manager);
```

redirect yout page to url for authentication

add this code on /status url

```
SocialAuthManager manager = (SocialAuthManager)session.getAttribute("authManager");

   AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(paramsMap);

  // get profile
  Profile p = provider.getUserProfile();

  // you can obtain profile information
  System.out.println(p.getFirstName());

  // OR also obtain list of contacts
  List<Contact> contactsList = provider.getContactList();
```